# Create an object of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

The structure which I want to get:

```
[
        {
            id: 'some id',
            name: 'Name',
        },
        {
            id: 'some id',
            name: 'Name',
        }, 
        // more arrays
]
```

and here is how I get the data

```
$students = get_posts( $args )

foreach ( $students as $student ) {
     $id = $student->ID;
     $name = $student->post_title;
}
```

now how can I convert the above data to the structure I want?
thanks

Comment: Your desired output is actually an array of objects...

Comment: we have an object [] and bunch of arrays {}, no?

Comment: no, `{}` is an object, and `[]` is an array

Comment: I'm assuming the output is JSON, so even if you create it as an array then they will be encoded as objects.

Comment: @Nick is this just php or in js {} is object too?

Comment: It's JS, and the JSON-encoded form of a PHP array of objects, or a PHP array of associative arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is not a valid PHP structure, but I'm assuming you meant you want the equivalent as a PHP array.

```
//create empty array to add subarrays to
$array = array();

//loop through values
foreach (get_posts($args) as $student) {

     //add subarray to array. using `[]` this way means "add to next sequential array key"
    $array[] = array(
        'id' => $student->ID, 
        'name' => $student->post_title
    );
}
```